# Complex action on Django menu

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a small app for a local hockey league, I wanted to know if it was possible to write an action on the admin of the games, so that when I check 2 games, it exchanges the teams that are about to play.

Example team A vs team B -- team C vs team D, if I swap this with the action menu it should be team C vs team B -- team A vs Team D

Thats the general idea... anyone has any suggestion? or ideas on how to achieve this!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a method like this:

```
def exchange_team(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if queryset.count() == 2:
        #your interchange code...
```

And reference it in your admin class:

```
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = ['exchange_team']

admin.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```